# Rails 4.2 Ensuring uniqueness across two columns in DB as well as on instance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am learning Rails right now as we transition a product to it. I have a problem -- and a definite lack of core skills with ruby -- that I am wondering how to address. Not only would I like an answer, I would welcome opinions on whether or not there is a better way to achieve this.

**Associations**:

We have a `Client` class which `has_many` `:users`. The `User` `belongs_to` the `Client`.

In addition to the `:client_id` column we also have a `:email` column that should be unique within the scope of the `:client_id`

**Validations:**

I have seen that I could do something like this to ensure that on the instance level by adding this check to the `User` model.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: {scope: :client_id}
```

but as far as my understanding goes, this does nothing to ensure uniqueness in the schema. Keep in mind I am trying to avoid manually altering the schema with SQL, I would like to do this with migrations if possible. In other uniqueness checks(for non scoped uniqueness), to ensure the uniqueness of something I would do something like this in the migration:

```
add_index :users, :email, unique: true
```

but that doesn't really do what I want, I don't think.

Tips, tricks, comments, suggestions, and answers welcome!

**Edit:**
MySQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
email VARCHAR(200),
client_id INTEGER,
UNIQUE INDEX (email, client_id)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array as the second argument to add_index in your migration:

```
add_index "users", ["client_id", "email"], :unique => true
```

This should produce:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_client_id_email ON users(client_id, email)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index